# Find a user_id from string where id is one digit or 2 digit using SQL Server query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server

Here is my C# code

```
private DataTable bindTrainingAttendeedGridView(string condition)
{
    DataTable dtGrid = new DataTable();
    con.ConnectionString = constr;

    string query = "select training_id,CONVERT(varchar(10),training_date,101) AS Training_date,topic,trainee from tbl_training_attendee where 1=1 " + condition;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    SqlDataAdapter sqladapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    sqladapter.Fill(dtGrid);

    if (dtGrid.Rows.Count <= 0)
    {
        Label1.Text = "No Matching Training taken Entries Found, Thank You.";
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "";
    }

    //con.Open();
    return dtGrid;
}

protected void TrainingAttendenceGridViewBind(string condition)
{
    try
    {
        TrainingAttendeedGridView.DataSource = bindTrainingAttendeedGridView(condition);
        TrainingAttendeedGridView.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception er)
    {
        throw er;
    }
}

protected void training_attendence_condition()
{
    string condition = "";

    if (UserDropDownList.SelectedIndex > 0)
    {
        condition += "AND PATINDEX('%61%',trainee)!=0 or(PATINDEX('%,61,%',trainee)!=0 and PATINDEX('%,61%',trainee)!=0 and PATINDEX('%61,%',trainee)!=0 ) 
    }

    TrainingAttendenceGridViewBind(condition);
}
```

In `training_attendence_condition`, I can write a query for getting `user_id` for that row but it can show only two digit number records and when take one digit number then it can return that number with second digit. So please help to get both one or two digits

[image]

Comment: Dont store your trainees in CSV in a text field, store them in a separate table

Comment: You also need to learn how to use parameterized queries. What you have here is potentially vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Your try/catch logic is bad. Only catch an exception if you plan to actually do something (handle the problem and/or log details about the problem). Don't just catch to rethrow, and definitely don't do `throw er;` where `er` is the caught exception - you'll lost your stack trace. If you need to throw it at the end, just do `throw;`.

Comment: you need to convert CSV to List of integer then it is easy to get data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this SQL query no need of training_attendence_condition you can directly write query as given :

```
select training_id,CONVERT(varchar(10),training_date,101) AS Training_date,topic,trainee from tbl_training_attendee where CONCAT( ',',trainee,',') like CONCAT( '%,','61',',%' )
```